# Get C# file fields and properties using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match (select from .cs file) property names, field names and places where they are used using regular expression.

This is example class:

```cs
using System;
... // usings
using Grpc.Net.Client;
using UI = Gtk.Builder.ObjectAttribute;

namespace DummyProject;

public class MainWindow : Window
{
    [UI] private readonly MenuItem _aboutMenuItem;
    [UI] private readonly MenuItem _openFolderItem;
    [UI] private readonly MenuItem _openFileItem;
    [UI] private readonly Viewport _fileViewport;
    [UI] private readonly Notebook _codeNotebook;
    private readonly SourceView _codeSourceView;
    private readonly FileViewer _fileViewer;
    private readonly Files.FilesClient _filesClient;
    
    public FileSystemViewer FileSystemViewer { get; }
    
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        _fileViewer = new FileViewer();
        // some code
    }

    // methods
```

Result will be: `_aboutMenuItem`, `_openFolderItem`, `_openFileItem`, `_fileViewport`, `_codeNotebook`, `_codeSourceView`, `_fileViewer`, `_filesClient`, `FileSystemViewer`

I've tried this regular expression: `^(?:(?=[^()]*$))?(?:(?!.*\b(namespace|return|using|class)\b))[\t \b]*(?:[\[\]a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\s+)?(?:(?:private|public|protected|internal)\s+)?(?:(?:static readonly|static|const|readonly|volatile|virtual|override)\s+)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)\s+)?(\w+)\s*`

But this regex matches incorrectly (see https://regex101.com/r/ZbctGa/3)

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to parse an irregular language with regex?

Comment: Regex is not the right choice here. Use a C# parser. Check out Roslyn.

Comment: Why not compile it and pull out the info using reflection?

Comment: @ThomasWeller thanks a lot for the hint, I think the solution to my problem lies precisely in using Roslyn instead of regex

Comment: @InSync thanks for comment, i'm developing a dotnet/csharp oriented code editor, and i thought that syntax highlighting can be implemented using regexes (i.e. find the right piece of text with a regex and highlight it), but ThomasWeller gave me a hint that this problem should be solved with Roslyn

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to capture the *properties* and *fields*.

```
(?:public|private)(?! class) (?:readonly )?(?:.+?) (.+?)[ ;]
```

Output

```
_aboutMenuItem
_openFolderItem
_openFileItem
_fileViewport
_codeNotebook
_codeSourceView
_fileViewer
_filesClient
FileSystemViewer
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use literal spaces rather than `\s` or `\s+`? 

`(?:public|private)(?!\s+class)\s+(?:readonly\s+)?(?:.+?)\s+(.+?)[\s+;]`

In this pattern, we would handle for extra spaces in the source code between different works/properties etc.